# Tag synonym request : [naming] <-- [names]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Both tags [naming](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) and [names](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names) are being used for questions related to terminology or naming conventions. They should be made synonymous.

I prefer [naming](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) to be the primary. Alternatively, we could map both to a [naming-conventions] tag (or similar).

Comment: Hmmm, some of the "name" questions seem to instead be "terminology" questions (separate tag). Not sure which makes it more clear that they're separate. We should probably pick a good tag wiki for a description. We also have "usernames" so I'm not 100% sure where to draw the lines--just "real names" for naming, usernames for system names/pseudonyms, terminology for "what's it called when..." ?